# Formatting in writing to file

Tags: python, output

I'm doing a project for an intro to Python class where I have to create a gradebook. In this gradebook, I need to display the number of students with each grade letter value and write it to a file. Everything works, it doesn't break or anything, but when displaying, it looks like this:

```
(1, " students got A's")
(2, " students got B's")
(3, " students got C's")
(4, " students got D's")
(5, ' students failed')
```

when I want it to look like this:

```
1 students got A's
2 students got B's
...and so on
```

How do I fix this? I could probably turn it in as is, but I'd rather the output not look bad. Full code for reference:

```
#1 Open file
WriteTo=open("ClassNameGrades.txt", "w")

#2 Initialize variables
MoreStudents="Yes"
A=0
B=0
C=0
D=0
F=0

#3 Inputs and writing
ClassName=input("What is the class called? ") + '\n'
TeacherName=input("What is the teacher's name? ") + '\n'
WriteTo.write(ClassName)
WriteTo.write(TeacherName)

#4 Loop student inputs
while MoreStudents=='Yes':
    Name=input("What is the student's name? ")
    Grade=input("What is the student's grade number? ")
    WriteName=str(Name)
    SpaceName = ": "
    IntGrade=int(Grade)
    WriteGrade=Grade + '\n'
    WriteTo.write(WriteName)
    WriteTo.write(SpaceName)
    WriteTo.write(WriteGrade)
    #5 Assigning letter to grade
    if IntGrade>=90:
        A=A+1
    elif IntGrade>=80:
        B=B+1
    elif IntGrade>=70:
        C=C+1
    elif IntGrade>=60:
        D=D+1
    else:
        F=F+1
    MoreStudents=input("Are there any more students? 'Yes' or 'No'")


#6 Assigning what to write in the file
PrintA=A," students got A's"
PrintB=B," students got B's"
PrintC=C," students got C's"
PrintD=D," students got D's"
PrintF=F," students failed"

#7 Writing to file
WriteTo.write(str(PrintA))
WriteTo.write("\n")
WriteTo.write(str(PrintB))
WriteTo.write("\n")
WriteTo.write(str(PrintC))
WriteTo.write("\n")
WriteTo.write(str(PrintD))
WriteTo.write("\n")
WriteTo.write(str(PrintF))

#8 Display in program
print(ClassName)
print(TeacherName)
print(PrintA)
print(PrintB)
print(PrintC)
print(PrintD)
print(PrintF)
```

Comment: instead of casting PrintX to a string, use 'join'

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
PrintA=A," students got A's"
```

… that creates a tuple of two values.

When you call `str` on a tuple like this:

```
WriteTo.write(str(PrintA))
```

What you get is the two values in parentheses, exactly as you're seeing.

---

If you want to format the results in some specific way, you have to do that explicitly, either instead of making a tuple:

```
PrintA = f"{A} students got A's"
# ...
WriteTo.write(PrintA)
```

… or instead of just calling `str` on the tuple:

```
WriteTo.write(f"{PrintA[0]} {PrintA[1]}")
```

The first version is probably more readable for your case, but in some real-life apps there might be reasons to prefer the second instead.

---

That "f-string" formatting requires Python 3.6. If you're using 3.5 or 2.7, you can use `str.format` instead:

```
PrintA="{} students got A's".format(A)
```

… or you can just do direct string methods if you find `format` hard to understand:

```
PrintA = str(A) + " students got A's"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already get this result:

```
(1, " students got A's")
(2, " students got B's")
(3, " students got C's")
(4, " students got D's")
(5, ' students failed')
```

For each one of these you only have to change the first element to a string and join them together.

```
def helper(in): 
    return str(in[0]) + in[1]
helper((5, ' students failed'))
>>>"5 students failed"
```

So simply place the function in your code and modify each thing you are printing using it:

```
WriteTo.write(helper(PrintA))
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines like:

```
PrintA=A," students got A's"
PrintB=B," students got B's"
PrintC=C," students got C's"
PrintD=D," students got D's"
PrintF=F," students failed"
```

Are actually defining `tuples` and when a `tuple` is printed out it's first converted to a `str`, which makes it look like `(x, y)`, so it prints:

```
(1, " students got A's")
```

Instead, what you want to do is create the `str` directly, like so:

```
PrintA=str(A) + " students got A's"
PrintB=str(B) + " students got B's"
PrintC=str(C) + " students got C's"
PrintD=str(D) + " students got D's"
PrintF=str(F) + " students failed"
```

So that when it's printed out (as a `str`) it will come out like:

```
1, students got A's
```